# Non-void method call statement works, why?

Tags: java, object, methods

I understand the basic concept of methods in Java. You call it, its code is executed, and it returns a value.

`length()` method of a String object (say, `str`) returns an `int` value, so we call it like this: `int x = str.length();`, `for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)`, etc.

`substring(int)` and `substring(int, int)` methods (also of the String class) return a String value, which we use like `String s = str.substring(3, 5);`, `String removed = str.substring(0, i)+str.substring(i+1);`, etc.

All of these examples are valid statements in Java.

However, these are not: `5;` or `"Hello there!";` or `'@';` or `add(2, 3);` where `add()` returns an int value.

This is pretty basic. But my problem is this: `str.length();`, `str.charAt(0);` and almost all String methods when called directly are valid statements, even if they do not have `void` for their return type.

Even a Scanner object can call methods directly like `scannerObject.nextLine();`, and is a valid statement.

So why? Why is `5;` invalid, and `str.length()` valid, even though it may also be equivalent to `5;`? What constitutes a statement in Java, why are local methods invalid statements, and why are object method calls allowed, even though they function similarly and return the same thing?

Comment: I tried searching for similar questions, but there aren't enough keywords in my question to search for something similar properly.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.8

Comment: @shmosel I'll check it out. Thanks.

Comment: @shmosel I've checked out your link, but it really doesn't offer much explanation to **my** question. It merely tells me that method call statements are allowed, but not why, and isn't related to my question.

Comment: Which part of your question was not answered?

Comment: `add(2, 3)` doesn't work? I've tried it just now, it's working.

Comment: `5` is a literal, and literal alone is not a valid statement in java.

Comment: @Prashant I did read the necessary related part though.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thanks for your answer!